# TextView doesn't work correctly - why so?

Tags: android, string, textview

I want to squeeze text into the program. I wrote everything as it should be in the code, but nothing came of it.

[image]

> Why my code don't work?

```
<string name="ph_mochi"><b>Норма:</b> 5.0–7.0/n <b>Загальні відомості</b>/n Реакція сечі (рН) залежить від кількості вільних водневих іонів Н+, утворючися в результаті дисоціації органічних та неорганічних кислот. В дистальній частині ниркових канальців іони Н+ виділяються в сечу, де в основном зв\'язуються з буферними основами і тільки не велика частина їх виводиться з сечею в вільному вигляді./n/n Свіжа сеча здорової людини може мати різну реакцію (рН від 4,5 до 8) в звичайних умовах реакція сечі слабколужна (рН 5–6). Коливання рН сечі залежить від складу харчування: м\'ясна дієта обумовлює кислу реакцію сечі, перевага рослиної та молочної їжі призводить до олужнення сечі. Зміни рН сечі відповідає рН крові. При <i>ацидозах</i> сеча має кислу реакцію, при <i>алкалозах</i> лужну. Розходження цих показників призводить до хронічних вражень канальців нирок. /n/n Бактеріальний розклад сечовини в сечоводах чи зберігання сечі при кімнатній температурі призводить до олужнення сечі. Реакція сечі впливає на солеутворення при сечокам\'яної хвороби:/nпри рН ниже 5,5 чаще утворюють сечокислі;/nпри рН від 5,5–6,0 оксалатові;/nпри рН вище 7,0 фосфатні камінці./n<b>ПІДВИЩЕННЯ рН:</b>/n/n•Метаболічний та респіраторний алкалоз/n•Нирковий канальцевий алкалоз/n•Бактеріальне розкладення сечовини/n•При вегетеріанській дієті/n•Гиперкаліємія/n•Хронічна ниркова недостатність/n•Новоутворення органів сечостатевої системи/n•В результаті цитрата натрію, бікарбонатів, альдостерону./n/n<b>ЗНИЖЕННЯ рН:</b>/n•Метаболічний та респіраторний ацидоз/n•Гіпокаліємія/n•Обезводнення/n•Голодання/n•Цукровий діабет/n•Лихоманка/n•Виражена діарея/n•Прийом лікарських препаратів: Аскорбінова кислота, Кортикотропін, Метіонін, Хлорид амонію/n•Дієта з великим вмістом м\'ясного білка, клюкви</string>
```

textView

```
<TextView
                    android:id="@+id/result"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

with

```
<string name="ph_mochi_1"><br><b>Норма:</b> 5.0–7.0</br><br> <b>Загальні відомості</b></br><br> Реакція сечі (рН) залежить від кількості вільних водневих іонів Н+, утворючися в результаті дисоціації органічних та неорганічних кислот. В дистальній частині ниркових канальців іони Н+ виділяються в сечу, де в основном зв\'язуються з буферними основами і тільки не велика частина їх виводиться з сечею в вільному вигляді.</br><br> </br><br> Свіжа сеча здорової людини може мати різну реакцію (рН від 4,5 до 8) в звичайних умовах реакція сечі слабколужна (рН 5–6). Коливання рН сечі залежить від складу харчування: м\'ясна дієта обумовлює кислу реакцію сечі, перевага рослиної та молочної їжі призводить до олужнення сечі. Зміни рН сечі відповідає рН крові. При <i>ацидозах</i> сеча має кислу реакцію, при <i>алкалозах</i> лужну. Розходження цих показників призводить до хронічних вражень канальців нирок. </br><br> </br><br> Бактеріальний розклад сечовини в сечоводах чи зберігання сечі при кімнатній температурі призводить до олужнення сечі. Реакція сечі впливає на солеутворення при сечокам\'яної хвороби:</br><br>при рН ниже 5,5 чаще утворюють сечокислі;</br><br>при рН від 5,5–6,0 оксалатові;</br><br>при рН вище 7,0 фосфатні камінці.</br><br><b>ПІДВИЩЕННЯ рН:</b></br><br> </br><br>•Метаболічний та респіраторний алкалоз</br><br>•Нирковий канальцевий алкалоз</br><br>•Бактеріальне розкладення сечовини</br><br>•При вегетеріанській дієті</br><br>•Гиперкаліємія</br><br>•Хронічна ниркова недостатність</br><br>•Новоутворення органів сечостатевої системи</br><br>•В результаті цитрата натрію, бікарбонатів, альдостерону.</br><br> </br><br><b>ЗНИЖЕННЯ рН:</b></br><br>•Метаболічний та респіраторний ацидоз</br><br>•Гіпокаліємія</br><br>•Обезводнення</br><br>•Голодання</br><br>•Цукровий діабет</br><br>•Лихоманка</br><br>•Виражена діарея</br><br>•Прийом лікарських препаратів: Аскорбінова кислота, Кортикотропін, Метіонін, Хлорид амонію</br><br>• Дієта з великим вмістом м\'ясного білка, клюкви</br></string>
```

don't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Android Studio Tutorial - Html Text View](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NFOt9M-2bKs&t=61s)
This video is good lesson about that theme.

```
htmlTextView.setHtml();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `Html.fromHtml`

```
TextView tvData = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvData);
tvData.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.ph_mochi)));
```

Comment: `/n`must be written as `\n`. user <br> tag instead of \n to break the line

Comment: Maybe I must use `SpannableStringBuilder`?